# Neo4j import tool bad tolerance uses default value

Tags: neo4j

I am importing data to neo4j database using neo4j import tool. I receive  "Too many bad entries 1001, where last one was neo4j import" error, though I have --bad-tolerance parameter to 99999999 since I have ~1.5bln nodes.

I cant figure out why I am getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079637/whats-going-wrong-with-the-phase-of-importing-relationships

Comment: well, this thread is more related to errors when creating relationships rather than --bad-tolerance argument functionality @michael-hunger - any ideas on this one?